# Как сделать select widget недоступным для редактирования

Tags: django

Есть следующее поле в форме:

```
self.fields['faculty'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(Faculty.objects.all())
```

Необходимо его сделать неактивным, но так, чтобы при POSTинге формы, он передавал значение этого неактивного поля.

Вариант `self.fields['faculty'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True`, не подходит, так как все что он делает, это красит селект в серый цвет.

Вариант `self.fields['faculty'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True`, реально блочит поле, но не передает значение при POST, поэтому тоже не подходит.

Есть ли простой способ это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать его disabled, и тут же, в конструкторе формы, если он disabled, прописать в self.data значение по умолчанию. Собственно, это в любом случае придется делать, потому что злохакер может убрать disabled в браузере и поменять значение.

Comment: а то, что возможно будет программно подменить значение, в моем случае не важно, главное, чтобы нельзя было изменить ручками

Comment: сделайте self.data = self.data.clone() перед модификацией

А что значит "ручками" и "программно"? Вот я зайду к Вам на сервис, открою web inspector, удалю атрибут "disabled", поменяю значение в селекте, и оно отправится к Вам на сервер.

Comment: self.data это обычный dict, у него нету метода clone() :(
А насчет "ручками", я имел ввиду без всякого просмотра исходного кода страницы. Просто форма с этим полем будет доступна только администратору, сомневаюсь, что он захочет хакать сам себя)

Comment: Если self.data это обычный dict, то он mutable :)

Comment: ну по крайней мере из-за self.dict.clone() вылезло Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'clone', а при изменении self.data вылезло This QueryDict instance is immutable, даже не знаю, что же это, QueryDict или dict -_-

Comment: что такое self.dict ?

Comment: опечатался в комментарии, там self.data

Comment: Напишите тест, посмотрите, что реально передаете в data в форму. Это уже совсем оффтопик выходит.